# Cascading combo boxes in VB.Net with Datatables using Designer

Tags: vb.net, datatable, combobox

I found this tutorial and am trying to make it fit my needs using the designer. I could design the data tables using the designer in VB.net but when I try to execute, I am getting an error on this line `Dim dv As DataView = combo2.DataSource`

https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1534892

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    With BooksView
        .Table = DataSet1.Books
    End With

    With Combo2
        .DisplayMember = "BookName"
        .ValueMember = "BookID"
        .DataSource = BooksView
    End With

    Call Me.SetCombo2(Combo1)

End Sub
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: you need to set Datasource property for combo2 control

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.'

Comment: Well in the example combo2 datasource is BooksView, which is of type DataView, so you probably changed something there because that should work. Check the code `With Combo2 ...  .DataSource = BooksView`, and make sure `BooksView` is a DataView.

Comment: i have set books as a datasource for combo box 2

Comment: `Books` is a DataTable. The example uses `BooksView` which is a DataView

Comment: how do i select DataView in combobox datasouce property..there is no such thing as dataview there

Comment: I changed the Dim dv As DataView = booksview . now the error disappeared but combobox2 shows all the values ..and cascading doest work. no changes. any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: now i have the above code and it works ..but is there a way to do without writing that combo2 properties and doing it only from the designer.?